# Reduce undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following model structure. ClassType has many Programs, Program has many Classes.

I am trying to get all the new classes for a class type:

```
def new_classes
    programs.reduce { |count, program| count + program.classes.new_classes.count }
end
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
undefined method `+' for #<Program:0x00000003535518>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

You need to give the initial value of your `count`, otherwise it will be the first element (which is of class `Program`):

```
def new_classes
    programs.reduce(0) { |count, program| count + program.classes.new_classes.count }
end
```